# I have an error but dependencies include in gradle root and gradle module config, why?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-data-jpa

I have root config gradle.build

```
plugins {
        id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.5.RELEASE'
        id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
        id 'java'
        id 'idea'
    }
    idea {
        project {
            languageLevel = 14
        }
        module {
            downloadJavadoc = true
            downloadSources = true
        }
    }
    allprojects {
        group "ru.otus"
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
            maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
        }
        apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
        dependencyManagement {
            dependencies {
                imports {
                    mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.5.RELEASE")
                }
                dependency("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16")
                dependency("org.springframework.shell:spring-shell-starter:2.0.1.RELEASE")
                dependency("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.3.5.RELEASE")
                dependency("org.flywaydb:flyway-core:6.4.4")
                dependency("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.16")
                dependency("org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3")
                dependency("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.3.5.RELEASE")
            }
        }
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                failOnVersionConflict()
            }
            resolutionStrategy {
                force("javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.4")
                force("commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1")
                force("commons-lang:commons-lang:2.5")
                force("org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.8.8")
                force("org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.8.3")
                force("org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:1.1")
                force("org.javassist:javassist:3.24.0-GA")
                force("org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0")
                force("org.opentest4j:opentest4j:1.2.0")
            }
        }
    }
```

and have build.gradle in module

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'


dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.shell', name: 'spring-shell-starter', version: '2.0.1.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter', version: '2.3.5.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'org.flywaydb', name: 'flyway-core', version: '6.4.4'
    testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-core', version: '1.3'
    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '2.3.5.RELEASE'
}
```

After download dependencies and add in models annotations like @Entity, @Table @Id and etc. i have an error: cannot find symbol
@Entity
^
symbol: class Entity
But i have spring-boot-starter-jpa in dependencies, i don't know why in module i can't use dependencies.

Comment: Because you don't have that dependency. You only added it to the dependency management section which isn't about adding a dependency but managing the versions etc.

Comment: how a can add it to dependency in "allproject" section add scope "dependencies" and put all dependencies ?

Comment: Thanks, it's working

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, please write answer, i select like right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dependencyManagement` you only manage dependencies like version, overrides etc. you don't actually add dependencies to a project. For that use `dependencies` like you use in the other places.